# How to fix mysql data encoding

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm working on a database that the names was saved in using `latin1` character set encoding (`latini_swedish_ci` collation) but the names were in Persian.


It seems some body changed the table collation to `utf8` (`utf8_bin`) but still the data is like this :

[image]

I'm wondering how can I fix this values.

I changed table collation and `DB` collation but still I have this kind of values.
Any help will be appreciate.


***Thank's in advance***

Comment: You will need `utf8_general_ci`. It is like Arabic. and make sure that the database, the table and the field have the same collation.

Comment: What is the scripting language that you use in your application?

Comment: All the types have the same collation. I think this data was maded using phpNuke... I'm trying to write a search engine that will be work independently...

Comment: Will your search engine application base on PHP too?

Comment: Could you maybe add a name for us with the characters - it's really hard to try different things with the names only in the image.

Comment: Terminology:  "character set" is what you are talking about, not "collation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you had

- utf8-encoded bytes in the client, and
- `SET NAMES latin1` (or equivalent), and
- `CHARACTER SET latin1` on the target column.

The "fix" to clean up the table is to do the 2-step ALTER [described here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#2_step_alter), which involves

```
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARBINARY(...) ...;
ALTER TABLE Tbl MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(...) ... CHARACTER SET utf8 ...;
```

where the lengths are big enough and the other "..." have whatever else (`NOT NULL`, etc) was already on the column.

Sorry, but it will take a long time do fix 1500000  rows.

I am pretty sure this will *not* work:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;  -- no
```

It would work only if the table currently contains the latin1 (etc) equivalent of the utf8 characters.  There is no latin1 equivalent for Arabic characters.

(I see it as Arabic:  Ø¨Ø§Ø³Ù„Ø§Ù… --> باسلام)

Comment: +1 was looking for a good description + example which should do the trick - another +1 for the hit that this will working for all character with latin1 equivalent.

Comment: @Rick James Thanks for your time. I followed your steps but still the data is like before. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Let's verify something else.  Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some small amount of text in the table.  And, if possible, tell me what it should look like.  (If you have "double encoding", the cure is even worse.)

Answer (score 1):

Change to `utf8_unicode_ci` like (To change the default character set and collation of a table including those of existing columns - **convert to** - is here the key part)

```
alter table <some_table> convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The `_ci` suffix means sorting and comparison happens case insensitive. so that shouldn't be a problem.

UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode character set, which should support pretty much every language in the world.

The only difference comes with sorting your results, different letters might come in a different order in other languages (accents, umlauts, etc.). For example comparing *a* to *ä* might behave differently in another collation.

---

Could you maybe add a name for us with the characters - it's really hard to try different things with the names only in the image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I used your query but the problem still remains...!!! Both table and columns have the same encoding---> `utf8_unicode_ci`

Comment: Could you dump us the table with some rows? - would like to try it directly so i can provide you a real solution.

Comment: let me try to... it's a huge database with more than 1500000 record....
I'll try to upload dump file some where..

Comment: simply copy & paste the table create statement & 10 - 20 insert statements - should be enough. 

Maybe the problem is not coming from the mysql part - could you also show us how you add these data?

Comment: I dumped first 100 rows. this the link
http://cld.persiangig.com/preview/34kcGttYB8/_book_authorbook002_.sql

Comment: According to the dump your table is still `utf8_persian_ci`

Comment: As I told to our other friend, I did not add any data to this table. I'm writing a search programm using php. but  phpmyadmin don't show right data either my script...

Comment: I changed it after your query, because of testing `convert` keyword with other type of encoding..

Comment: I saw the answer from @Rick James which should do the trick for your tables - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29711023/1581725

Comment: @DominikAngerer - Somehow your link to my page points to this page instead.  Keep in mind that there are different things that can happen; and they have different solutions.  [See blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#how_mangling_happens_on_insert).

Comment: @RickJames The link provided above directs to your answer on this page where he can find the solution + the link to your blog - btw reading it right now - really interesting.

Comment: Oops, I see what you mean about the link.  I have struggled a long time to come up with the information in that blog.  Alas, lots of people still need the information in it.  And I continue to find new or better info to put in it.

Comment: Have some struggles with the layout of your page - if you are interested in a sideproject and recreating your blog - let me know www.dominikangerer.com

Comment: I do understand that my layout is lame.  If the content is mangled, please provide some details.

Comment: nothing wrong with the content - simply thought about usability - but I don't like to discuss this on a question we didn't solve yet.